# simulate hitting time of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, simulation

let's say I have a brownian motion $W_t$, and I know the value of $W_1$.
Is there a way to simulate the hitting time of $W_t$ and a given function $f(t)$ ?
For instance I know that if $f(t)$ is a constant, the first hitting time of a constant A has a density that is known explicitely, but I'm assuming that for more complex function f, there is a not always a closed formula ? 
In that case, is there a known algorithm to simulate the first time t, such that $f(t) = W_t$ ?

thanks!

Comment: For general $f$ I guess that you just simulate until for some step $t_i$ of the simulation $W_{t_i} \geq f(t_i)$.

Comment: As I recall you can get first passage time densities more or less explicitely for linear functions with a Girsanov change of measure. For more general I can't recall well, but there were some known results.